# Drum fill generator

Tags: code-golf, random

Create a program that generates a drum fill. Your program will output a pattern of `L` (left hand hits), 'R' (right hand hits), and `K` for kick drum hits.

### Rules

- The pattern must never have more than 2 of the same hits consecutively.
- The pattern must be loopable, so it mustn't have more than 2 of the same hits when it loops.
- Your program accepts 1 argument which is the length of the pattern. You can assume this will always be an integer > 1.
- Program output must be random each time it's ran.
  It should be properly random each time, so that every combination is possible, so for an input of 2 for example: LR, LK, RL, RK, KL, KR all have a chance of being generated.
- IO can be used with any convenient method.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- This is code-golf, so smallest program wins!

**Example valid output:**

```
RLRRKKLL
LRLLKKLR
LKKRLRKLRRKL
LRLR
```

**Example invalid output:**

```
LRLL // 3 characters when looped
LRLRRRLLR // 3 characters in a row
RRLRLLRR // 4 characters when looped
```

Comment: No it should be properly random each time, so that every combination is possible, so for an input of 2: LL, LR, LK, RR, RL, RK, KK, KL, KR all have a chance of being generated. I'll add something to the rules about that now.

Comment: I've made those changes to the question, cheers!

Comment: May we output using three other distinct characters instead of L, R, K? (e.g. A, B, C or 2, 3, 9)

Comment: "The pattern must never have more than 2 of the same hits consecutively." What is this mean? Should I read for output `hits[]`, `forall i: hits[i] != hits[i+1]`? But the example output `RLRRKKLL` doesn't agree on what I mean.

Comment: @tsh *more than 2*, not *2 or more*.

Comment: @Adám So, does it mean \$ \forall i: hits_i = hits_{i+1} \implies hits_i \ne hits_{i+2} \$?

Comment: @tsh i'd make that \$hits_{i+1\bmod n}\$ and \$hits_{i+2\bmod n}\$, but yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
…LRKãʒDJÅγà3‹}Ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//@KApkxSS8OjypJESsOFzrPDoDPigLl9zqn//zQ)

```
…LRK                # literal "LRK"
    ã               # strings made of `input` of those letters
     ʒ       }      # filter:
      DJ            #  concatenate the string with itself
        Åγ          #  run-length encode
          à         #  maximum (largest run length)
           3‹       #  less than 3?
              Ω     # get a random element
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“LRK”ṗ;`E3Ƥ$ÐṂX
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4oCcTFJL4oCd4bmXO2BFM8akJMOQ4bmCWP///zQ)**

#### How?

Pretty similar to [Nick Kennedy's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197748/53748) Jelly answer...

```
“LRK”ṗ;`E3Ƥ$ÐṂX - Link: integer, n
“LRK”           - "LRK"
     ṗ          - Cartesian power (all length n strings with alphabet "LRK")
            ÐṂ  - keep those entries which are minimal under:
           $    -   last two links as a monad:
      ;`        -     concatenate with itself
         3Ƥ     -     for each infix of length 3:
        E       -       all equal?
              X - random element
```

Comment: ... but 1 byte shorter! Nice.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 67 bytes

```r
n=scan();while(max(rle(c(x<-sample(c("L","R","K"),n,T),x))$l)>2)0;x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVIzexQqMISCdrVNjoFifmFoDZSj5KOkpBQOytpKmTpxOiqVOhqamSo2lnpGlgXfHfyOA/AA)

A full program taking an integer, n and implicitly printing the drum pattern.

Comment: I didn't notice the clever use of pasting the values together to duplicate the vector so  for a while thought it was possible to get something like LRLL.  Very nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
“LRK”ṗ;`ŒɠṀ<ʋƇ3X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4oCcTFJL4oCd4bmXO2DFksmg4bmAPMqLxoczWP///zM)

A monadic link taking the length \$n\$ and returning a Jelly string of the drum pattern. Like the other answers, assumes that \$n > 1\$

### Explanation

```
“LRK”ṗ           | Cartesian power of "LRK" and n
            ʋƇ   | Keep those where the following is true:
      ;`         | - Concatenate to itself
        Œɠ       | - Lengths of runs
          Ṁ      | - Max
           <  3  | - Less than 3
               X | Pick one at random
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>115</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>112</s></sup> 104 bytes

```python
from random import*
f=lambda n,s='L':any(b*3in s*3for b in'LRK')and f(n,''.join(choices('LRK',k=n)))or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxDsIwDIXhvafwFjuyGAgwVOoJ6MQNkpaoBupUSZeePgSGp394@rZjX5K6WmNOK2Svc4usW8q77eLw8WuYPSiXwYym93pgsE4UinUxZQggasbH3VCTEFHZmNMrieK0JJmeBf8vvwclogZK/TFpDNDxmS9tjq98o76DLYvuGFGI6hc)

Saved a byte thanks to [Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown)!!!
Saved 8 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!!!

Comment: [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY07DsIwEET7nGI7r4NFgYECKScgFTfIx1YWyNpaG6Gc3jgUoynmPU3c8hLYluIlrCADz7VojUFy28zOg0c2qVN9r/Stge9CbwcDbzi2lhjSIYEPAiMQq/5xr1CF1fEZiHFaAk0u4X8wr461bkBc/kgVy65R1QCtOZlzjTUXc91fohBn9Ehalx8) by using `from random import*` (a common trick).

Comment: Some improvements: 1. `import*`; 2. recursive `lambda` function; 3. multiply string (avoiding a space); 4. multiply by 3 (initial `s='L'` rather than `s='LL'`). [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcsxDsIwDIXhvafwFjuyGAgwVOoJ6MQNkpaoBupUSZeePgSGp394@rZjX5K6WmNOK2Svc4usW8q77eLw8WuYPSiXwYym93pgsE4UinUxZQggasbH3VCTEFHZmNMrieK0JJmeBf8vvwclogZK/TFpDNDxmS9tjq98o76DLYvuGFGI6hc)

Comment: @ChasBrown Tried a few different `import`s but none of them saved any bytes -Thanks so much !! :-)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Totally amazing! Was trying to think of something recursive but didn't get anywhere. Also very clever changing over to `s='L'` and `s*3`! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 30 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
{'LRK'[?⍺⍴3]}⍣{~1∊≢¨3∪/⍺,2↑⍺}⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rdJ8hbPdr@Ue@uR71bjGNrH/Uurq4zfNTR9ahz0aEVxo86VukD5XSMHrVNBNJA6RX/0x61TXjU2/eob6qn/6Ou5kPrjUGSfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/tEMrHvVuNjUAAA)

`{`…`}`…`⍨` apply the following function using the single argument also as left argument:

`'LRK'[`…`]` index into the string `"LRK"` using the following indices:

`⍺⍴3` reshape the number three into the length indicated by the left argument

`?` random indices in those ranges

`⍣{`…`}` keep applying that function until the following is true:

`2↑⍺` take the first two characters of the previously generated string

`⍺,` prepend the previously generated string

`3∪/` the unique elements in each window of width three (lit, the union-reduction)

`≢¨` the length of each set

`1∊` is one a member thereof?

`~` negate

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
`?`=diff;n=scan();while(!all(??c(x<-sample(9+c(2,3,9),n,T),x)))0;LETTERS[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8E@wTYlMy3NOs@2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVQzExJ0fD3j5Zo8JGtzgxtwAoZKmdrGGkY6xjqamTpxOiqVOhqalpYO3jGhLiGhQcXRH738jgPwA)

Rejection sampling until an allowable pattern is found. Samples \$x_i\$ from the set \$\{11, 12, 18\}\$ (the positions in the alphabet of K, L, R). Agreeably, these numbers are such that a pattern is allowable iff \$\forall i,  (x_{i+1}-x_i)-(x_i-x_{i-1})\neq 0\$. This condition is verified by calling `diff` twice (`diff` computes lagged differences, and here we want the lagged differences of the lagged differences).

Comment: How about [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVIzexQqMISCdrVNjoFifmFoDZSj5KOkpBQOytpKmTpxOiqVOhqamSo2lnpGlgXfHfyOA/AA) for 67 bytes?

Comment: @NickKennedy Smart! I always forget about `rle`. You should post this separately IMO.

Comment: ok thanks! Have done so it

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
->x{0while /(.)\1\1/=~(w=(%w(L K R)*x).sample(x)*'')+w;w}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166i2qA8IzMnVUFfQ08zxjDGUN@2TqPcVkO1XMNHwVshSFOrQlOvODG3ICdVo0JTS11dU7vcurz2f0FpSbFCml5yYk6OhpEmFzLXGJVrgso1ReWaaf4HAA)

Comment: You can save two sweet bytes by using `?redo:w` instead of `0while `+`;w`. See https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWqPIVkO1vNpHIUjBu1YrT1OvODG3ICdVI09TS0lJU8vItk5fQ08zxjDGUN@@KDUl36qo9n@BQlq0cex/AA (I had come up with this answer before seeing yours, but it was too close and you got in first.)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>77</s>  74 bytes

Assumes that the input is greater than \$1\$.

```javascript
n=>(g=s=>s[n-1]?/(.)\1\1/.test(s+s)?g``:s:g(s+'LRK'[Math.random()*3|0]))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dce9DoIwEADgnae4jZ6EQnUDCw@gLq5A0oY/NXg1XOOiPntl@vI97Ntyv95fPiU3jGHSgXQlZs264oZS1dWZkNiqVmXSj@wFJ4z1bEzBxbwlPl9PcXOx/iZXS4N7CtwdvnmHaEyY3CoINOxLIDiCyjeTBOETAfSO2C2jXNwsJkGIZfQLfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔KηＷ⊙KLR№×η³×κ³≔⭆θ‽KLRηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLsbg4Mz1PQ8lbSUchA8gvz8jMSVXQcMyrBIr5BAFFnfNL80o0QjJzU4s1MnQUjDV1FCCcbBAHCBSgZgSXFGXmpfsmFmgU6igEJeal5OdCzNDUhJgdAJQv0QCy/v@3/K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Hangs for an input of `1` (could be changed to output a random hit at a cost of 1 byte). Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number of hits.

```
≔Kη
```

Initialise the output to an illegal value.

```
Ｗ⊙KLR№×η³×κ³
```

Repeat while the output is illegal, determined by tripling the output and each of the three letters `K`, `L` and `R`, and checking whether one contains any of the others.

```
≔⭆θ‽KLRη
```

Assign the desired number of randomly selected letters to the output.

```
η
```

Output the final legal result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 86 bytes

```perl
$_=R x("@F"+2);1while s|(.)(?=\1\1)|(R,L,K)[rand 3]|e;s/..$//;($_.$_)=~/(.)\1\1/&&redo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jZIoUJDycFNSdtI09qwPCMzJ1WhuEZDT1PD3jbGMMZQs0YjSMdHx1szuigxL0XBOLYm1bpYX09PRV/fWkMlXk8lXtO2Th@oHqRYX02tKDUl//9/03/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYkAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 97 bytes

```ruby
->x,y=->{[*1..x].map{%w[L R K].sample}}{a=y[];a=y[]while(a+a).chunk{|n|n}.any?{|_,e|e[2]};a.join}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcfBCoIwGADge0@xS@BKf8jKi2gPUKeuY8SfTLTmkmzo2PbsCzq1ywffW99NaElFQlYvqamy2rLNDmDhMOBo1zO7kCs5c5hwGKXw3mJlGC9/zl0vRYJbpNB0Wj2tU055QGVO1t1S4QTLuS8RHq9e@TDqz0RaaFDKJKer/@7jHuIe4xY0fAE)

This is a lambda function, which takes the length input as `x`.
It creates a function `y` which generates a list of length `x` containing random characters from the list `["L", "R", "K"]`. It then checks to see if there are any repeating occurrences of more than 2, and if so recreates a random string.

The `chunk` method on an array groups consecutive elements.

I check for any repetitions on `(a+a)` (where `a` is the generated drum loop), to find any looping-round repetitions.

### Golfy Tricks

- Using `e[2]` instead of `e.size > 2` - this works as everything is truthy in Ruby except `nil` and `false`, and indexing out of bounds in an array returns `nil`.
- Using `%w[L R K]` instead of `["L","R","K"]` or `[?L,?R,?K]` - This is ruby's [whitespace-separated word array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/what-does-warray-mean).

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>141</s> 112 bytes

```
func[n][until[s: copy""loop n[append s random/only"LRK"]parse
rejoin[s s][any[copy t skip opt t ahead not t]]]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1LDsIwDET3PYWVC/BZ9gqw6tbyIiKuCBTbilOhnj40qLsZad6bwqlNnJCGEiXp5@TMCUS/wzy2eZUHCuEqNS/oIzzUthAWVQPBaMaSwOEgVZYt3KdbIIvFeSj80izo4IRRNuwwVPB3NlCre4xPjv1sz0Tk1P7myxlQxsPam5UsFdD6Fq4wgxC1Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 55 bytes

```perl6
{({S:g{.}=<R L K>.pick}...{!/(.)$0$0/}o*x 2).tail}o\*x*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WqM62Cq9Wq/W1iZIwUfB206vIDM5u1ZPT69aUV9DT1PFQMVAvzZfq0LBSFOvJDEzpzY/RqtC6781V3FipUKagul/AA)

Anonymous code block that takes an integer and returns a string of `RKL`s.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
                                                  o\*x*  # Generate a string of n *s
{                                                }  # And pass to code block
 (                     ...                 ).tail   # Get the last element of the sequence
  {                   }      # Where each element is
   S:g{.}=       # Substitute each character of the previous string with
          <R K L>.pick   # A random character 
                          {          }      # Until
                                      o*x 2 # The double of the string
                           !                # Does not
                            /(.)$0$0/       # Contain three of the same character in a row
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 43 bytes

```
pe"LRK"jCB{J?+gw)-]>]3.<}f[sa0#Rx/x/jrn-]!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/IFXJJ8hbKcvZqdrLXju9XFM31i7WWM@mNi26ONFAOahCv0I/qyhPN1ZR8f9/YyNDUwUTAA)

Made trickier by the fact there is no "select random element from list" as far as I am aware. 15 bytes are just trying to select a random element.

```
pe      # Push inputs onto stack takes "SEED N"
"LRK"   # Literal LRK
jCB     # Form all combinations of length N
{
 J?+    # Double string
 gw     # Zip with length of consecutive vals
 )-]    # Take length
 >]     # Maximum
 3.<    # Less than 3
}f[     # Filter for
sa0     # Find number of matches
#Rx/x/j # Fiddle stack to get SEED 0 num_matches
rn      # Gen random ints
-]!!    # Select the first
```